# Poor parameter estimation in frailty models

Tags: survival, recurrent-events, frailty

I fitted a  one-parameter gamma shared frailty model with Weibull and exponential baseline hazards for recurrent event data (the dataset contained 80 subjects of which 16 patients had events (13 subjects with just one event, 2 subjects with 2 events and one subject with 3 events)) and I found:

1. The Weibull and exponential scale parameter very large (about 4000) with a standard error of  3000. What could be the meaning of this?
2. The estimate for the variance of the frailty ($\theta$) is also large (about 15), with a standard error of about 7.2.
   Can I interpret this value of theta (15) as high between cluster variability? Or does the high standard error change its interpretation?

Note that model convergence was achieved. Can someone help please.